# Sentry privileges on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera-cdh, apache-sentry

I have a question regarding Spark privileges with Sentry on Hadoop cluster.

First, some background -

1. I'm using CDH version 5.13.2
2. ACL sync on HDFS is enabled
3. Impersonation disabled
4. Grant on database level and for specific cases gants on URI

**Scenario**

There are two databases, db_a and db_b. In db_a there is a view which selects from table which is defined in db_b.

I granted privilege for a specific user with read access (grant select) on db_a.

In Beeline/Impala/Hue the behavior is as expected:

- show databases shows only db_a
- when user's query the view in db_a it works perfect even the user don't have any privilege on db_b.

The problem with Spark SQL:

- When the same user is trying to access the view in db_a, it's failed as user don't have access to db_b.

Again, same query with same user works fine in Hive/Impala.

Is there any configuration or workaround to resolve the problem?